# Best Way To Get URL Params in Angular 6/7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular7

What is the best way to get the URL parameters of: foo, bar, baz

```
https://somesite.com/results?foo=123&bar=69&baz=456
```

I have tried:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
    let foo = param['foo'];
    let bar = param['bar'];
    let baz = param['baz'];
})
```

This works, but it fires twice with the first time being undefined and the second time with values. I have also read this is a bad way to do it and being depreciated in the future.

The second method I tried is:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
     console.log(evt.url);
    }
 })
```

This logs the correct URL but does not parse it. How would you parse it and is this an effective method?

What is the best way to solve my issue in Angular6/7?

Comment: "it fires twice with the first time being undefined" where did you call your code?

Comment: I am callign it in ngOnInit();

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.param1 = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('foo');
    this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('bar');
    this.param3 = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('baz');
}
```

## or,

```
constructor(
public route:ActivatedRoute){
}

    ngOnInit(){
    const self = this;
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
                self.foo= params['foo']; 
                self.bar= params['bar']; 
               self.foo= params['foo']; 

            });
    }
```

Comment: The first example returns 'null' for every param. The second returns the correct result but fires twice like my first example. The first firing returns undefined and the second time fires the result.